# Computational power of Turing machines vs circuit ensemble

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, circuits

Is it true that for every Turing machine , there exists a circuit ensemble  such that () = (), or is it true that for every circuit ensemble , there exists a Turing machine  such that () = ()?

Initially, I believed that the second statement was true because a Turing machine can simulate any circuit ensemble. However, upon further investigation, I discovered that the first statement is actually true while the second one is false. I have been unable to find a satisfactory explanation or proof for this, and I would greatly appreciate clarification on the matter. Many thanks.

Comment: Another question here suggests that a circuit ensemble is a mapping $ℕ → C$ where $C$ is the set of circuits, with a condition on what sort of output is allowed given the input. If that's the notion you're using, then it would be unsurprising if an _uncomputable_ mapping from numbers to circuits allows an ensemble's language to be uncomputable. However, this then means there is essentially no systematic procedure for describing the circuits in the ensemble, so one might question how realistic such ensembles are.

Comment: 1. Please [edit] your post to define in a self-contained way what you mean by "circuit ensemble".  2. Please ask only one question per post.  I see two questions here.  Please pick one to ask.  If you have two questions, you can ask them separately in two separate posts.  3. You say you "discovered that the first statement is actually true while the second one is false".  Please clarify the basis for this belief.  Can you credit the source where you saw this or the evidence you have for this statement?